# Firebase Security Rules - Checking if data.hasChild and keeps failing

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have a security rule that looks like this:

```
"user_feeds": {
     "$userId": {
        ".indexOn": ["timestamp"],
        ".read": "auth != null",  
         "$postId" : {
           ".write": "auth != null && newData.parent().hasChild(newData.child('band_id').val())"
           }
         }
       }
```

in my `$postId` sub-tree, I'm trying to check to see if the parent has a node that corresponds to the `band_id` value of the data that is being inserted.

The data looks like:

```
{
   post_id: 1,
   band_id: '-L-tyesfsdf13434',
   timestamp: 34234234234
}
```

And an actual tree that these rules would correspond to look like:

```
{
   "user_feeds": {
     "userId1": {
        "-L-tyesfsdf13434": true
     }
   }
}
```

I am using Ionic/Angular and here is my function that's actually trying to do the write operation:

```
addPostToFollowers(bandId, postId) {

    // 1. Get the user's connections
    this._bands.getBandFollowers(bandId).take(1).subscribe(connections => {
      if(connections.$value !== null) {
        delete connections['$key'];
        delete connections['$exists'];

        let connectionKeys = Object.keys(connections);
        // 2. Go through those connections and add the post
        let bandFeeds = {};
        connectionKeys.forEach(connectionKey => {
          bandFeeds[`/user_feeds/${connectionKey}/${postId}`] = {
            post_id: postId,
            band_id: bandId,
            timestamp: -(+(new Date()))
          }
        })

        // 3. Update the social feeds
        this.db.object(`social`).update(bandFeeds);
      }
    })
  }
```

However, when I try to run this, I get a permission denied and I have no idea why. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: After posting my answer, I tested both your rule and mine.  Both work, so my statement about the limits of `newData()` seems incorrect.  Can you post the code that attempts to write a new post?

Comment: Really, you got it to work? I had tried using `root` to find it and it still gave me permission denied :/

Comment: Yes, I think the rule is valid.  I'll look at your update.

Comment: Hey I actually figured it out. I had to tweak a few things and I realized I was failing to reference another path correctly. I'll add my answer, but thanks for looking into this for me :)

Comment: It looks like `user_feeds` is a child of location `social`.  Is that right?  If so, the permission check for the `update()` uses the rule for  location `social`, not the children.  Do you have a rule for `social`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `root.child('user_feeds').child($userId)` instead of `newData.parent()`:

```
"user_feeds": {
 "$userId": {
    ".indexOn": ["timestamp"],
    ".read": "auth != null",  
     "$postId" : {
       ".write": "auth != null && root.child('user_feeds').child($userId)
                    .hasChild(newData.child('band_id').val())"
       }
     }
   }
```

I suspect the `newData` snapshot is limited to the data at that location and `parent()` cannot be used to fetch data at a location higher in the database tree.

Answer (score 0):

So here are my updated rules. I needed to reference another path correctly:

```
"user_feeds": {
    "$userId": {
       ".indexOn": ["timestamp"],
       "$postId" : {
          ".write": "auth != null && (root.child('social').child('user_band_follows').child($userId).hasChild(newData.child('band_id').val()) || root.child('social').child('user_band_follows').child($userId).hasChild(data.child('band_id').val()) || root.child('social').child('user_connections').child($userId).hasChild(auth.uid))"
     }
  }
}
```